# Twitter login result is empty

Tags: android, twitter

I'd like to implement `Twitter authentication` in my app and to do that I followed the steps in official documentation. I have tried with `TwitterLoginButton` and `TwitterAuthClient`. Both of these do the same thing, set a callback return to `onActivityResult` and if it's successful step into the success method or if it's not into the failure.

My problem is that I do not get my data from the result. Username, id, token everything is null. Here is my code I hope you have some idea.

```
twitterAuthClient.authorize(activity, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                TwitterSession session = result.data;
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                String token = authToken.token;
                String secret = authToken.secret;
                Timber.d("Twitter successfull login by client",session.getUserName());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Timber.d(exception, "Twitter login failed");
            }
        });
```

or

```
loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @SuppressLint("TimberArgCount")
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
            TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
            String token = authToken.token;
            String secret = authToken.secret;
            Timber.d("Twitter successfull login by button",session.getUserName());
        }

        @SuppressLint("TimberArgCount")
        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Timber.d(exception, "Twitter login failed");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fellow this steps its worked with me**

1 - in your build.gradle dependencies put this

```
implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:2.3.0@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
```

2 - in your activity put this

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig));
TwitterAuthClient client = new TwitterAuthClient();
```

3 - override onActivityResult

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TwitterAuthConfig.DEFAULT_AUTH_REQUEST_CODE)  // twitter stuff
         client.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

4 - just keep your code

```
client.authorize(activity, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                TwitterSession session = result.data;
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                String token = authToken.token;
                String secret = authToken.secret;
                Timber.d("Twitter successfull login by client",session.getUserName());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Timber.d(exception, "Twitter login failed");
            }
        });
```